# How to store a result of an OpenCL kernel without taking it to a host to reuse it in another kernel?

Tags: c, optimization, opencl

I have two kernels in my app:

```c-like
__kernel void
set_decomposition_key(
    __global const double* values_ref,
    __global const double* decomposition_results_ref,
    __global double* decomposition_keys)
{ /* Some code, results are put into decomposition_keys */ }

__kernel void
decompose(
    __global const double* values,
    __global const double* decomposition_keys,
    __global double* decomposition_results)
{ /* Some code, results are put into decomposition_results */ }
```

`set_decomposition_key()` executes once when the app's starting, it puts its calculation results into the `decomposition_keys` value. Then `decompose()`, the main function, comes into play: it executes in a loop performing some operations in real time. It uses results of the first function stored in `decomposition_keys` as its second parameter. So the thing's that I want to keep this variable in an OpenCL device's memory without taking it to a host and then setting again for the second kernel every loop.

But I don't know how to do this, my attempts to find a working solution by myself failed. So I'll appreciate any help here. Thank you in advance.

Note: I know about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13363603/17939216), suddenly it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the host side, make one `cl::Buffer decomposition_keys;` object and link it to both `cl::Kernel set_decomposition_key, decompose;` objects via `setArg(...);`.

When you call `set_decomposition_key`, it writes the results into the `decomposition_keys` array in device memory, and the data stays there unchanged. You can call the kernel `decompose` over and over again, it only reads `decomposition_keys`. The array stays in device memory and no copying to host memory is required.

Note that on the host side, `cl::Buffer decomposition_keys;` must remain in scope for the buffer not to be deleted on the device side. For testing, you can ensure this by setting it as a global C++ variable.

---

For an easier start with OpenCL/C++, try this [OpenCL-Wrapper](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper). It makes buffer handling on the C++ side so much easier and shorter.

Comment: I'm using `cl_mem decomposition_keys_buffered = clCreateBuffer(main_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 640 * 480 * sizeof(cl_double), NULL, &error_code)`, is this the same? It's definitely a global C++ variable, but it still doesn't work. Actually, this app doesn't give any errors, it finishes successfully, but doesn't return any result. On the other hand, the same code but with those two kernels merged into the one (so `decomposition_keys` are calculating at every iteration) returns correct results.

Comment: That's the C bindings, they work the same. Can you share the C++ code where you create/call kernels? I would assume the issue is with that.

Comment: Sorry, I can't show this because it's covered by business secrets of a company where I'm currently working. But I've understood your point, so for now I'm also thinking that my mistake is different than what I thought. Thank you.